How to set up my first github repository?
I have always put off creating a github repository because of the learning curve.  Now I know I was right!  I want to set up a public repository to make available some code for using lewansoul servos.  I tried using this guide, but I soon started to get error messages.
I started with:
git config --global user.name "fredbloggs"
git config --global user.email "fredbloggs@gmail.com"
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global core.editor geany

I also set up ssh authentication successfully:
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi fredbloggs! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Then I went into my project directory and tried to set up the repository. I managed to resolve the following jargon-rich errors:
fatal: No configured push destination.

fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.

ERROR: Repository not found.

I had to create the repository in github first, and then I used the following commands:
cd lewansoul-lx16s
git init
git add lx16a.h main.py newlx16a.c README.md .gitignore
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git branch -M master
git remote add origin git@github.com:fredbloggs/lewansoul-lx16a.git
git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 5.57 KiB | 5.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: error: GH007: Your push would publish a private email address.
remote: You can make your email public or disable this protection by visiting:
remote: http://github.com/settings/emails
To github.com:fredbloggs/lewansoul-lx16a.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (push declined due to email privacy restrictions)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:fredbloggs/lewansoul-lx16a.git'

The final error has me stumped.  I don't want to publicise my email address, so I followed some advice to set a virtual email and ran:
git config --global user.email "33916898+fredbloggs@users.noreply.github.com"
...but this does not resolve the error.  What should I do now?
I'd also really appreciate a guide to setting up a simple, public repository that actually works.

ssh -T git@Hi fredbloggs!  this doesn't look right at all

You can turn off email restrictions or rewrite your git history

@Phil - you are right.  I edited the question to correct the cut&paste error. tmaj - yes, the comment you linked helped me.  I had not understood the part about amending 'history' (which Daniel also pointed out).

Simple solution:

Create a new repository using Github web site.
Follow the instruction on the screen and set up your local repository.


How to try and fix your problems.

Github prevents you from using your private email.

Go to your account settings:
https://github.com/settings/emails and uncheck the checkbox





As you mentioned you should do the following and it did not help:

# Set "private" github email
git config --global user.email {ID}+{username}@users.noreply.github.com

###
### You missed this part
### Reset the author information on your last commit:
###
git commit --amend --reset-author

Next: push your code

It is true that I missed the part about resetting information from last commit.

For (push declined due to email privacy restrictions) please see Meaning of the GitHub message: push declined due to email privacy restrictions.
For setting up the repo, follow GitHub's own Start your journey where the 3rd section is the Hello World page that starts with:

In this quickstart guide, you will:

Create and use a repository.
Start and manage a new branch.
(...)


Good luck!
